# Reverse HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, reverse, sorting

I have a `HashMap` which looks like :

`HashMap<Player, Integer> playerHashMap = new HashMap<>();`

Player is object which contains name, number, age etc.

And now I've sorted it, and it loookts like this:

```
key    , value
-----------------
Player1, 1
Player2, 2
Player3, 4
Player4, 6
```

But I want to achieve reverse this map by value, like this:

```
key    , value
-----------------
Player4, 6
Player3, 4
Player2, 2
Player1, 1
```

Any idea ?

Sorting method (sorted by value) looks like this:

```
private static HashMap<Player, Integer> sortByValues(HashMap<Player, Integer> map) { 
           List list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());

           Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Object>() {
                public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                   return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
                      .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());
                }
           });

           HashMap<Player, Integer> sortedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<Player, Integer>();
           for (Iterator<?> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                Map.Entry<Player, Integer> entry = (Map.Entry<Player, Integer>) it.next();
                  sortedHashMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
           } 
           return sortedHashMap;
      }
```

Comment: "*now I've sorted it*" that doesn't sound real since HashMap doesn't guarantee any order. If you mean that you ware able to print them in described order than what is stopping you from printing it in different order?

Comment: How did you "sort" your HashMap? Where is the code for that?

Comment: I edit my post and add how looks method to sorting HashMap.

Comment: well, it's hard to imagine more inefficient way to achieve this sorting...

Comment: I'm guessing what you really want to do is convert `HashMap<Player, Integer>` to `HashMap<Integer, Player>`. You don't need to do any sorting to achieve that.

Comment: I want create "Top List" and HasMap contains `Player` and his goals (which I count before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you sort this?
The (basic) HashMap does't defines order between elements.
I use this:

```
    public static <K extends Comparable<K>,V> List<Entry<K,V>> sortByKeys(Map<K,V> map, final Comparator<K> cmp)
{
    List<Entry<K, V>> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Entry<K,V> kv : map.entrySet())
        ret.add(kv);


    Collections.sort(ret,((Comparator) new Comparator<Entry<K,?>>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<K, ?> o1, Entry<K, ?> o2)
        {
            return cmp.compare(o1.getKey(), o2.getKey());
        }
    }));

    return ret;
}
```

you can specify your comparator to order the returned List of Entry order.

=====

Edit:
It's a good idea to use a Map implementation which care about order.
You can simply modify your code to specify ordering, just modify the header and this one line:

```
-private static HashMap<Player, Integer> sortByValues(HashMap<Player, Integer> map) {
+private static HashMap<Player, Integer> sortByValues(HashMap<Player, Integer> map, final boolean reverse) {
```

and in the block:

```
-return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
+return (reverse?-1:1)*((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
```

Comment: It works :) Thanks ! I know this that my try is not good but I it was my first idea to resolve my problem. I have database which contains many Events of Player and I want easy to get Player and his goals from Events table

Comment: In java element comparision applied by the return value (just positive, negative or zero) of a comparator. Behind the scene java calls the comparator with two elements need to be compared and by the return value the sorting algorithm decides what to do. Magnitude of values doesn't care just it is negative or zero or null. So if you doesn't change the sign of the comparator's return value yo get ascending ordered map, if you do (multiply with -1) you get reverse order.

Answer (score 2):

The truth is HashMap doesn't garantee any particular order of iteration. So you just 'got lucky' that your list got sorted in any way at all. To solve your problem you has to sort table rows as one entity, so that `value` is linked to corresponding `player`. To do so, you can actually use Map.Entry's directly, and put them to collection, but you will need a custom comparator. In your example it's better to use the usual `ArrayList` for the task, and that sort it with `Collections.sort()`. To reverse the order, negate the result that you return from comparator:

```
class Player {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Player, Integer> all = new HashMap<>();
    List<Map.Entry<Player, Integer>> sorted = sortByValues(all);
    for (Map.Entry<Player, Integer> e : sorted) {
        System.out.println("Player: " + e.getKey());
        System.out.println("Value: " + e.getValue());
    }
}

private static List<Map.Entry<Player, Integer>> sortByValues(HashMap<Player, Integer> map) {
    List<Map.Entry<Player, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Player, Integer>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<Player, Integer> e1, Map.Entry<Player, Integer> e2) {
            //use minus to reverse the order
            return -e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
        }
    });

    return list;
}
```

Comment: It also loooks nice ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use java.util.TreeMap and pass a comparator to sort them the way you want.

However I still wonder why you have Player as a Key and an Integer as a Value ?
If you are using Integer only for sorting, then you might want to swap the Key and the value for a better standard way of using Maps. 
Also if you don't have a need to access the Objects using a hashing technique (that is if your collection is not going to be huge where hashing would improve the performance) consider a simple List.

Comment: Key is Player, because I need access to all his information and Value is Integer because it represents number of goals which I count and increase before.

Comment: If the ordering is the only thing you have to achieve, you can do that by reversing the items in your compareTo method, (swap o1 and o2) or add a - to the expression before return

  return - ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
                      .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());

Either way, I would still reconsider the design, either to have no.of goals as key or as an attribute in the Player object. But I will leave that decision to you as you know the application better. Try the above tweak to reverse sort them.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you want to return separate Map. You already have List which you could simply sort by value of stored entries.
Also don't limit yourself with specific types of Maps like HashMap. You gain probably nothing but you make changing your implementation to other type of Map very hard.

So your code could look like:

```
private static List<Map.Entry<Player, Integer>> entriesSoltedByValue(
        Map<Player, Integer> map) {
    List<Map.Entry<Player, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());

    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<Player, Integer>::getValue).reversed());

    return list;
}
```

Or using streams:

```
private static List<Map.Entry<Player, Integer>> entriesSoltedByValue(
        Map<Player, Integer> map) {
    return map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator
                    .comparing(Map.Entry<Player, Integer>::getValue)
                    .reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short you cannot set a order to a `HashMap`. If you want the same functionality as a `HashMap` but with order you should use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

```
Map<String, Integer> orderedMap = new TreeMap(Collections.reverseOrder());
orderedMap.putAll(playerHashMap);
```

`HashMap` gives you O(1) inserting and searching while they are O(log(n)) in `TreeMap` because it is internally implemented with a Red-Black tree.